# How to remove a single quote from a value while inserting in SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have a long list of insert query which has a slight error.

```
INSERT INTO `delivery_zip` (..) 
VALUES ("AB'C / DEF", ..), ("AB'C / DEF", ..), ("AB'C / DEF", ..), ...
```

How do I remove the single quote after **AB'** from the values.

Comment: Is the above `INSERT` statement literally how you are inserting the data?  What would be wrong with doing a find and replace in a text editor?

Comment: You must be building this query using some kind of programming language like java , C#, ..etc . Try to write parameterized query or try to replace single quote while preparing query, doing the same in sql is not a good practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the single quote in question is the *only* single quote present in the column `col1`, and you have already inserted the data, then you should be safe using `UPDATE` with `REPLACE` to remove it:

```
UPDATE delivery_zip
SET col1 = REPLACE(col1, ''', '')
```

But if you haven't done the insertion yet, you could do a find and replace in your script first, possibly using a regex if needed.