# SQL: Remove outer only single quotes in column before inserting into row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a program that allows me to execute SQL after downloading an image. The program also provides tokens which give a specific value depending on the image downloaded. To do this it provides a form field which I have filled with:

INSERT INTO tag_index (tag, index_count) VALUES ("%type%:%tag%", 1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE index_count = index_count + 1;

I would expect this to insert `"location:italy"` into `tag_index`.

However, the values tokens return are surrounded by single quotes. Going by the previous example `"'location':'italy'"` gets inserted into `tag_index` instead.

Having these single quotes in `tag_index` is incompatible with the gallery application I am using, and I cannot edit the application I am downloading the images with to make the tokens not surrounded by single quotes. I need to be able to write a line of SQL that can fit in the downloader applications settings field that removes just the outer single quotes when inserting into `tag_index`.

For example, would it be possible to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO tag_index(tag, index_count) VALUES ("ESCAPEOUTERQUOTES(%type%):ESCAPEOUTERQUOTES(%tag%)", 1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE index_count = index_count + 1;
```

I am using MySQL 5.7.23.

**Edit**

As suggested by some comments, I do not think using `REPLACE` would answer my question. A `%tag%` token can include valid single quotes. For example, when a tag resembles a face `''o''` I need to only remove the outer single quotes leaving `'o'`.

Comment: which database you are using?  In my `REPLACE(str, find_string, replace_with)`

Comment: previous discussion --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052120/how-to-remove-a-single-quote-from-a-value-while-inserting-in-sql-database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a single quote from a value while inserting in SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052120/how-to-remove-a-single-quote-from-a-value-while-inserting-in-sql-database)

Comment: I don't believe so. A `%tag%` token can include valid single quotes. For example, when a tag resembles a face `''o''` I only want to remove the outer single quotes leaving `'o'`.

Comment: @BoneJones . . . If you cannot simply use `REPLACE()`, then you need much more explanation on what valid replacement are.

Comment: A valid replacement would include matching the outer single quotes for each token and removing them. I don't believe you can use regex in `REPLACE()` but maybe I am wrong?